# How general is the statement that "the gradient points in the direction of fastest increase"?

Tags: vector-analysis, inner-products, gradient-descent

Let $V$ be an arbitrary $n$-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb R$. Define the gradient of $f$ at $x$ as the vector such that for all $\mathbf v\in V$,

$${\displaystyle {\big \langle}\nabla f(x){\big )},\mathbf {v}\big\rangle =D_{\mathbf {v} }f(x),}$$

where $\langle,\rangle$ is the inner product on $V$ and $D_{\mathbf {v} }f(x)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ along the tangent vector $\mathbf v\in \mathbb R^n$.

**What do we need to assume to conclude that the gradient is the "steepest" direction in which to go?** Does this hold for arbitrary inner products? Or just the Euclidean one?

Comment: The correct definition for gradient is that for all $v \in V$,$ {\displaystyle {\big \langle}\nabla f(x){\big )},v\big\rangle =D_{v }f(x),}$. No need for $\mathbf{v}$...

Comment: @OlivierRoche, that was a typo, edited.

Comment: What is exactly the meaning of "steepest"? Can we say that $v$ is steeper than $w$ at $x$ if for small $t$, $\lVert f(x + t v) - f(x)\rVert \geqslant \lVert f(x + t w) - f(x)\rVert$?

Comment: @OlivierRoche, yes that is how I am thinking of it at least, with the additional constraint that the length (norm) of $v$ and $w$ should be equal.

Comment: Changing the inner product also changes the norm. But the norm is also involved in the definition of the differential.

Comment: Hint: On the unit sphere $\lVert\mathbf v\rVert=1$, when is $\langle\mathbf w,\mathbf v\rangle$ maximal for a fixed $\mathbf w$?

Comment: @amd, I'm not sure what the inner product space is? What is the inner product on the unit sphere? (and I assume do we pick the tangent vector $\mathbf v$ at an arbitrary point?)

Comment: I think you’ve misunderstood. You’re still in $V$, but w.l.o.g. you can restrict yourself to unit vectors when examining $D_{\mathbf v}$.